# How can I append whole columns to a table (list of lists) in python?

Tags: python, mysql, list, tuples

Given tuples like the following which are generated from mysql fetchall calls in a loop...

```
tuple1 = (('doug', 6), ('fred', 9), ('garth', 3))
tuple2 = (('steve', 3), ('dan', 1))
tuple3 = (('alan', 5), ('tom', 8), ('bob', 3), ('joe', 8))
```

How can I append each tuple as an entire column into a table (list of lists) like this?

```
table = [['doug',6,'steve',3,'alan',5],
         ['fred',9,'dan',1,'tom',8],
         ['garth',3,'',,'bob',3],
         ['',,'',,'joe',8]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the lists are of different size, `zip()` won't be useful here, so we have to implement our own `zip`-like function that accepts lists with different lengths, filling missing elements with `None`:

```
def transpose(lists):
   if not lists: return []
   return map(lambda *row: list(row), *lists)
```

Next, stick together all the tuples in a single list:

```
tuple1 = (('doug', 6), ('fred', 9), ('garth', 3))
tuple2 = (('steve', 3), ('dan', 1))
tuple3 = (('alan', 5), ('tom', 8), ('bob', 3), ('joe', 8))
tuples = [tuple1, tuple2, tuple3]
```

Now the answer is simple, written in terms of list comprehensions:

```
table = [[y for x in t for y in x or ['']] for t in transpose(tuples)]
```

The result is as expected:

```
table
=> [['doug', 6, 'steve', 3, 'alan', 5],
    ['fred', 9, 'dan', 1, 'tom', 8],
    ['garth', 3, '', 'bob', 3],
    ['', '', 'joe', 8]]
```

Regarding the question in the comments: how to add a new column to an existing table? here's how:

```
def addcolumn(table, column):
    tr = transpose([table, column])
    return [(x if x else []) + (list(y) if y else []) for x, y in tr]
```

Continuing with the example:

```
tuple4 = (('hewey', 1), ('dewey', 2), ('louie', 3))
addcolumn(table, tuple4)

=> [['doug', 6, 'steve', 3, 'alan', 5, 'hewey', 1],
    ['fred', 9, 'dan', 1, 'tom', 8, 'dewey', 2],
    ['garth', 3, '', 'bob', 3, 'louie', 3],
    ['', '', 'joe', 8]]
```

Comment: Wow Oscar... you talents are amazing.  What if I want to do it with a function "addcolumn", whereby I could now add tuple4 to the existing table?

Comment: @panofish Sure thing, take a look at my updated answer. I hope this is useful for you ;)

Comment: Oscar... you are amazing.  That's just what I needed!

Comment: If I create an empty table like this table = [] and then use addcolumn to add tuple1... I get an error "unsupported operand type".  addcolumn only works when adding to a table that already has data?

Comment: Yes. In fact, it'd be more efficient if you pass a list of tuples for creating the table, instead of adding them incrementally one by one

Comment: My full code is basically a loop which makes a mysql call each loop that returns a tuple.  I need to build the table by adding the tuple as a column and then repeat the loop.  Therefore, at the beginning, my table is empty and I may loop 1 or more times.... I need to think on this some more... I may understand what you are getting at... BUILD THE LIST OF TUPLES in my loop... then use the transpose logic to reorient my columns?... so I don't need the addcolumn function after all?

Comment: It's best if you collect all the tuples first in a list and then process them as a whole, that is: use the first version of my solution, it'll be faster than repeatedly calling `addcolumn()`